# ¿Cómo puedo asignar que no se suba 5MB el tamaño de adjunto en Apex? con dbms_lob.getlength

Tags: oracle, apex

INSERT INTO GGRANDEZ.TBL_ADJUNTOS_ANULACION
SELECT A. *,: P502030_ID_REGRISTO,
FROM APEX_APPLICATION_TEMP_FILES A
WHERE name =: P502030_ADJUNTOS;

I want to give the attachment a size that does not go up 5MB onwards since I do not have space in the BD, so something like dbms_lob.get_length is used and pass convert MB to verify

Comment: This is an English language site. Please ask your question in that language, or ask at [es.so] instead.

Answer (score 0):

select id, filename,created_on,dbms_lob.getLength(BLOB_CONTENT) adjunto
from TBL_ADJUNTOS_CAP
WHERE ID_REG = :P219_ID

Aqui ya lo estoy usando pero nose que tipo de datos para que no pase de 5MB

Comment: Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English-only site](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor explicar mejor el requerimiento? Necesitas controlar el tamaño de los archivos a cargar?